# what Software Center have done during Maxima CAS installation?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, software-center, synaptic

I want to install wxMaxima CAS on new Ubuntu 16.04 using software center ( USC) - prefered method. The process went without errors but wxMaxima is not working ( after clicking on the icon). But Maxima cas is working :

```
Maxima version: "5.37.2"
Maxima build date: "2015-10-30 02:08:33"
Host type: "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
Lisp implementation type: "GNU Common Lisp (GCL)"
Lisp implementation version: "GCL 2.6.12"
```

**My questions** :

1. How can I check what Software Center have done during installation ?
2. How to install wxMaxima properly ?
3. If wxMaxima is not installed properly thru USC why not remove it from it's list ?

**Edit 1**

As Byte Commander suggested I check also `/var/log/apt/history.log`

```
Start-Date: 2016-09-03  09:13:33
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-install-packages' sender=':1.83'
Install: maxima-doc:amd64 (5.37.2-8, automatic), wxmaxima:amd64   (15.08.2-1), fonts-jsmath:amd64 (0.090709+0-3, automatic), maxima-   share:amd64 (5.37.2-8, automatic), maxima:amd64 (5.37.2-8, automatic)
End-Date: 2016-09-03  09:13:38

Start-Date: 2016-09-03  09:27:15
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-install-packages' sender=':1.83'
Install: maxima-test:amd64 (5.37.2-8, automatic), maxima-src:amd64   (5.37.2-8, automatic), xmaxima:amd64 (5.37.2-8)
End-Date: 2016-09-03  09:27:17
```

I have also found  [wxmaxima_15.08.2-1_amd64.deb](http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/xenial/wxmaxima) but after :

```
apt list --installed >~/intalled.txt
```

there is a note

```
wxmaxima/trusty,now 16.04.2.1-1~ppa2~trusty amd64 [installed]
```

Does it install from ppa2 ?

**Edit 2**

When I check from console :

```
gcl
```

then :

```
Program gcl is not installed, use : sudo apt install gcl
```

next check :

```
apt-cache show gcl
```

result :

```
Package: gcl
Priority: optional
Section: universe/interpreters
Installed-Size: 209011
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Camm Maguire <camm@debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 2.6.12-29
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15), libgmp10, libreadline6 (>= 6.0), libx11-6,   debconf (>= 1.2.0), gcc, emacs24 | emacsen, ucf
Suggests: gcl-doc
Breaks: emacsen-common (<< 2.0.0)
Filename: pool/universe/g/gcl/gcl_2.6.12-29_amd64.deb
Size: 29429174
MD5sum: 118b8311e483a9fd37e35daa0ec3b959
```

but I think, it is probably not installed because synaptic shows that it is not installed.

Probaly GCL is not needed because package is compiled.

[**Bug report**](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wxmaxima/+bug/1620014)

Comment: You can look at `/var/log/apt/history.log` to see what actions the package manager has performed.

Comment: it looks that USC installed packages without crucial dependecies.

Comment: "It's well known that Maxima-draw is broken in Ubuntu 16.04 due to a
change in the GCL lisp compiler.  At present, the only workaround I know is to compile Maxima yourself. I have compiled it in my Xubuntu 16.04 with SBCL instead of GCL and it works as expected. " Mario Rodriguez